# Swift 3: Hexagon do not show center of the imageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My hexagon do not show in center of the imageView, how to fix this? Here is my code.

```
 func roundedPolygonPath(rect: CGRect, lineWidth: CGFloat, sides: NSInteger, cornerRadius: CGFloat, rotationOffset: CGFloat = 0)
        -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let theta: CGFloat = CGFloat(2.0 * M_PI) / CGFloat(sides) // How much to turn at every corner
        // let offset: CGFloat = cornerRadius * tan(theta / 2.0)     // Offset from which to start rounding corners
        let width = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)        // Width of the square

        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + width + 10 / 2.0, y: rect.origin.y + width / 2.0)

        // Radius of the circle that encircles the polygon
        // Notice that the radius is adjusted for the corners, that way the largest outer
        // dimension of the resulting shape is always exactly the width - linewidth
        let radius = (width - lineWidth + cornerRadius - (cos(theta) * cornerRadius)) / 2.0

        // Start drawing at a point, which by default is at the right hand edge
        // but can be offset
        var angle = CGFloat(rotationOffset)

        let corner = CGPoint(center.x + (radius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle), center.y + (radius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle + theta), corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle + theta)))

        for _ in 0 ..< sides {
            angle += theta

            let corner = CGPoint(center.x + (radius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle), center.y + (radius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
            let tip = CGPoint(center.x + radius * cos(angle), center.y + radius * sin(angle))
            let start = CGPoint(corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle - theta), corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle - theta))
            let end = CGPoint(corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle + theta), corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle + theta))

            path.addLine(to: start)
            path.addQuadCurve(to: end, controlPoint: tip)
        }

        path.close()

        // Move the path to the correct origins
        let bounds = path.bounds
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -bounds.origin.x + rect.origin.x + lineWidth / 2.0,
                                          y: -bounds.origin.y + rect.origin.y + lineWidth / 2.0)
        path.apply(transform)

        return path
}
```

[image]

Comment: a regular hexagon's width and height is not equal; `height = a; width = a * sqrt(3) / 2;` in your case; therefore you need to translate the points by `a * (1 - (sqrt(3) / 2)) / 2` or something.

Comment: Can you suggest me what i do in my code?

Comment: you need to apply the offset on every `x` coordinate, which aligns your hexagon to the desired location in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Both of this elements has `x` and `y` equals `0`. Try to use `width` properties to calculate transform.

Comment: @MianShahbazAkram, I already told You what to do, change `let transform = CGAffineTransform...` to use `width` and `height` properties instead of `x` and `y`.